# If $f\left(\cfrac{x}{x-1}\right) =\cfrac{1}{x} $ for all $x \ne 0,1$ and $0<\theta<\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ ,then find $f(\sec^2 \theta)$

Tags: functions

> If $f\left(\cfrac{x}{x-1}\right) =\cfrac{1}{x} $ for all $x \ne 0,1$
>   and $0<\theta<\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ ,then find $f(\sec^2 \theta)$.

I've worked out something but I belive it's not correct.

If we let $g(x)=\cfrac{x}{x-1}$ we have that $g(x)$ is a cyclic function of order $2$ ,thus we have $$f\left(\cfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-1}\right)=\cfrac{1}{g(x)}$$
$$f \left( x \right)=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{x}{x-1}}=\cfrac{x-1}{x}$$

So I have that $$f(\sec^2 \theta)=\cfrac{\sec^2 \theta -1}{\sec^2 \theta}=\cfrac{\tan^2 \theta}{\sec^2 \theta}=\sin^2 \theta $$

As already said,I am not sure this is correct as I've started recently studying this stuff.

Also are there other ways to solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice,  your method is correct.

setting $\frac{x}{x-1}=y\implies x=\frac{y}{y-1}$, one should get $$f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{\frac{y}{y-1}}=\frac{y-1}{y}$$
hence, $$f(\sec^2\theta)=\frac{\sec^2\theta-1}{\sec^2\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}$$$$=\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: Thanks sir.Actually I prefer the way you've solved the problem since it doesn't mention at all cyclic stuff etc..,which makes it easier to understand . +1